# Unexpected output in a simple C program

Tags: c

So, I tried to write a simple C program which would calculate multiplication of two numbers without using `*` operator. But the result is not coming as expected. I can't understand why. This is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=1,b=1,c=1,i;
    printf("\n 1st element=");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("\n 2nd element=");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    for(i=0;i<b;i++)
    {
        a=a+a;
    }
    printf("\n result=%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are a and b when you print them out?

Comment: @user814064, Why should I print b? I have printed a.

Comment: Before the for loop what are a & b?

Comment: @Mistu4u Since you're doing work with `b`, a good first step would be to find out what it is equal to.

Comment: "But the result is not coming as expected" It's also a complete mystery. Mind telling us what it was?

Comment: change `a=a+a` to `a+=a`

Comment: WTH is with all the code-only answers in this question. Is it friday already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply using shifts and adds.  O(log(b)).  Watch for overflow.

I recommend this method over a `for (t = 0; t < b; t++)`.  Imagine if you were using 64-bit math, the `for` loop would take a long time, even on a computer.  OP doubling method of `a=a+a` was on track, but incomplete.

```
unsigned a;
unsigned b;
unsigned product = 0;
scanf("%u%u", &a, &b);
while (b > 0) {
  if (b & 1) {
    unsigned OldProduct = product;
    product += a;
    if (product < OldProduct) {
      printf("\nOverflow\n"); 
      break;
    }
  b >>= 1;  // Halve b
  a += a;  // Double a - avoid using multiplication
}
printf("\nProduct = %u\n", product);
```

Comment: @Havenard Some folks like *= 2 others, <<= 1. The same until the sign bit gets involved. Likely best to do this exercise all in unsigned.

Comment: Sure but if the idea is to not use multiplication, what is that `*` doing there? See my point?

Comment: @Havenard I've taken off my foggy spectacles and I see the light.

Answer (score 4):

You are actually exponentially doubling `a` with your loop.

Say `b = 3` and `a = 5`, for example. Then the loop will run three times.

Unrolling the loop would yield:

```
a = 5; /* initial value of a */

/* now run a=a+a; three times */
a = 5 + 5 = 10;
a = 10 + 10 = 20;
a = 20 + 20 = 40;
```

So you won't get 15, but you will get 40.

Instead, make a new variable, like `sum = 0`, and then add the value of `a` onto `sum`, like this:

```
sum = 0;
for (i=0; i<b; i++)
    sum += a;
```

By the way, the `+=` operator is a great operator which simply adds the value on the right side of itself onto the variable that is on its left side. It's so much nicer and less ugly than the misleading equation `a = a + a`, which doesn't even make mathematical sense unless `a = 0`.

Comment: The mis-leading `a = a + a` may be part of a far more efficient method than the incremental for loop as this answer proposes.  It is standard idiom to multiply by doubling `a` each time through a loop.  The problem is that b should be halved each loop and a conditional product sum is needed.  This method could take quintillion iterations with 64 bit math.

Answer (score 2):

```
int a=1,b=1,c=0,i;

a=a+a; ==>c=c+a ;    

printf("\n result=%d",c);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int a=1,b=1,c=0,i;
for(i=0;i<b;i++)
    {
        c=c+a;
    }
printf("\n result=%d",c);
```